# discrepancy of data cast between matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, casting

I need to generate data for a MATLAB program, but my favorite language is Python. Thus I chose Python, however, I found a discrepancy between Python and MATLAB in the data cast. Could anyone give me a clue how came the results are not the same, and how can I make the same?

[image: cast in MATLAB]

[image: cast in python]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting float to integer, Matlab rounded your `5403.9` up to 5404, while Python rounded it down to 5403. You should decide which is more correct and fix the "wrong" one.

Answer (score 1):

Python always round to the floor int, Matlab doesn't
that's why in python:

```
np.array([5403.9125]).astype("int16")
```

is equal to [5403]

while in matlab:

```
int16(5403.9)
```

is equal 5404

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.